# Given a Date Object how do I determine the last day of its month?

Tags: java, date

I'm trying to use the following code but it's returning the wrong day of month.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(sampleDay.getTime());
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, sampleDay.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 0);
return cal.getTime();
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Get the number of days for this month:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(sampleDay.getTime());
int noOfLastDay = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Set the Calendar  to the last day of this month:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(sampleDay.getTime());
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

Answer (score 3):

I would create a date object for the first day of the NEXT month, and then just subtract a single day from the date object.

Comment: This seems to be the common pattern to solve this problem in any language.

Comment: some days are not 24 hours long, so this isn't an ideal solution.  It'd work 95% of the time though.

Comment: This is the more general-purpose language-indifferent solution.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
YearMonth.from(
    LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
).atEndOfMonth()
```

## java.time

The Question and other Answers use old outmoded classes. They have been supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). Much of the functionality has been back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone. While these objects store no time zone, note that time zone is crucial in determining the current date. For any given moment the date varies around the globe by time zone.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( zoneId );  // 2016-06-25
```

### `YearMonth`

Combine with the [`YearMonth`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class to determine last day of any month.

```
YearMonth currentYearMonth = YearMonth.from( today );  // 2016-06
LocalDate lastDayOfCurrentYearMonth = currentYearMonth.atEndOfMonth();  // 2016-06-30
```

By the way, both `LocalDate` and `YearMonth` use month numbers as you would expect (1-12) rather than the screwball 0-11 seen in the old date-time classes. One of many poor design decisions that make those old date-time classes so troublesome and confusing.

## `TemporalAdjuster`

Another valid approach is using a [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html).
 See [the correct Answer by Pierre Henry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46914556/642706).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you set the calendar to the first day of the next month, so you need one more line to subtract one day, to get the last day of the month that *sampleDay* is in:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(sampleDay.getTime());
cal.roll(Calendar.MONTH, true);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 0);
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
```

In general, it's much easier to do this kind of thing using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), eg:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(sampleDay.getTime());
return date.plusMonths(1).withDayOfMonth(0).minusDays(1).getMillis();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use calObject.getActualMaximum(calobject.DAY_OF_MONTH)

See [Real's Java How-to](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0098.html) for more info on this.

Answer (score 2):

## `TemporalAdjuster`

Using the (relatively) **new Java date API**, it is actually very easy :

Let `date` be an instance of `LocalDate`, for example :

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2018, 1, 22);
```

or

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
```

or, of course, you could get it as a user input, from a database, etc.

Then apply an implementation of the [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) interface found in the [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) class:

```
LocalDate first = date.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth());
LocalDate last = date.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [date4j](http://www.date4j.net) library:

```
DateTime monthEnd = dt.getEndOfMonth();
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this should work nicely:

```
Dim MyDate As Date = #11/14/2012#  'This is just an example date

MyDate = MyDate.AddDays(DateTime.DaysInMonth(MyDate.Year, MyDate.Month) - MyDate.Day)
```